# SQL query to return every user and their friends

Tags: sql, mysqli

Let's say you have a `users` table and a `friends` table. The friends table has the following columns

`user_id, friend_id`

I want to be able to get all the users from the `users` table and iterate through them to get their friends WITHOUT making another db call... Is there a way to do this?

if I have a `users` table with the following columns

`id, username`

I can get a user and do something this

`$result->username ... or $result->id`

but I want to be able to do this

`$result->friends`

Is there a way to somehow add this "fake" `friends` attribute using a sql query?

Comment: What is this fake friends attribute expected to be? A string of usernames or an array of users or ...?

Comment: The "fake" friends attribute is expected to be an array of user ids or a string of user ids... either one is fine @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the friends for each user as a comma separated list there is a GROUP_CONCAT function you can use in MySql. I have a left join here to get all rows from the `users` table, use an ordinary join if you only want users that has friends.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(f.friend_id)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JOIN's it might do the job

SELECT u.username, f.friend_id FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.user_id  = f.user_id

Or you do as below

SELECT u.username, f.friend_id FROM users u,friends f WHERE u.user_id  = f.user_id